# How to jump to the current playing song in foobar?

Tags: foobar2000

In iTunes there's a small icon in the title frame, by which we can jump to the current playing song in the play list. I'm wondering if there is some similar way to jump to the song currently playing.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You could also double click the status bar (if the track is still in one of your playlist; that's not always the case with playlists generated automatically or by browsing...)

Comment: You must have "Playback Follows Cursor" option disabled for this to work.

Comment: As an update to the previous comment, intervening Foobar2K updates seem to have fixed it to work whether or not that option's checked.

Comment: @SilverbackNet Agreed - doesn't need the option checked on 1.6.2.

Comment: Can confirm working on version 1.6.2

Answer (score 25):

From the [foobar2000 FAQ](http://www.foobar2000.org/FAQ):

> **How do I make the currently playing track to be selected (highlighted) and
>   stay always in view?**
>
> Enable “Cursor Follows Playback” under
>   main window's “Playback” menu.

[image: foobar2000 playback menu]

Answer (score 13):

The `Cursor follows playback` preference messes with me sometimes when I'm organizing a non-active playlist or doing other tasks. I've made a keyboard shortcut to go to the song being played only when I want.

- Open the `File` menu
- Open the `Preferences` window
- Click on `Keyboard shortcuts`
- Click on `Add new`
- Use the filter to find the `View` → `Show Now Playing` setting
- Assign it to any key or key combination you want. The below screenshot uses CTRL + J as a shortcut for it:

[image: foobar2000 screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

You can access the current playing song from the menu bar View -> Show Now Playing in Playlist. However this menu item is usually hidden. If you press the menu bar while holding the shift key however all the hidden commands will show.